chmod: cannot access x': No such file or directory
I have read the hdlmake 3.3 documentation and followed all the steps in the Linux deployment section, but I have encountered the following errors in CentOS:
[gms@localhost ~]$ chmod +x /usr/bin/hdlmake
chmod: cannot access '/usr/bin/hdlmake': No such file or directory

Here are my steps:
[root@localhost gms]# pip3 install hdlmake
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Requirement already satisfied: hdlmake in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
[root@localhost gms]# cd hdl-make
[root@localhost hdl-make]# python3.6 setup.py install
Copying hdlmake-3.3-py3.6.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
hdlmake 3.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing hdlmake script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hdlmake-3.3-py3.6.egg
Processing dependencies for hdlmake==3.3
Finished processing dependencies for hdlmake==3.3
[root@localhost hdl-make]# !/usr/bin/env bash
bash: !/usr/bin/env: event not found
[root@localhost hdl-make]# PYTHONPATH=/hdlmake python3.6 -m hdlmake $@
ERROR   main.py:71: hdlmake()   No manifest found in path: .
[root@localhost hdl-make]# PYTHONPATH=/sourcefiles/hdlmake python3.6 -m hdlmake $@
ERROR   main.py:71: hdlmake()   No manifest found in path: .
[root@localhost hdl-make]# chmod +x /usr/bin/hdlmake
chmod: cannot access '/usr/bin/hdlmake': No such file or directory

In hdlmake.readthedocs.io/en/master, it says, "Once the launch script has been created, the appropriate execution rights must be set: chmod +x /usr/bin/hdlmake", but I am getting error.
Also, on a separate note, my goal is to clone this GitHub repository: https://ohwr.org/project/vme-sbc-a25-pcie-vme-bridge. They have mentioned using hdlmake greater than 3.3, but it seems that the latest version is 3.3.
Please advise.

The error message tells you exactly what is happening:
chmod: cannot access '/usr/bin/hdlmake': No such file or directory

you're trying to change the permissions on /usr/bin/hdlmake, which does not exist.  Looking earlier in your text, it looks like you ran a setup.py script that installed /usr/local/bin/hdlmake, so that is probably what you want (chmod +x /usr/local/bin/hdlmake), but why the setup.py script doesn't do that for you already is not clear.
You also have some bogus invalid commands between the setup.py and the chmod -- not clear what you were trying to do there.
